# check variable in mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check a variable in my MySQL table and get some action done if it fits.
I want to check whether the logged in account has the type = d. If so, he should get redirected, if not the normal html code should appear.
But for now, it gets completly ignored.

This is my code

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");



    session_start();

   if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
}
    else {
        $now = time(); // Checks the time, the homepage gets loaded

        if ($now > $_SESSION['expire']) {
            session_destroy();
             header("Location: http://www.uni-landau.de/vivian/source/expiredLogin/expiredLoginLayout.php");
        exit();
    }
    else {
    ?>
    <?php include "connect.php"?>
    <?php include "functions.php"?>
    <?php

        $check_login = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
            $run = mysql_fetch_array($check_login);
            $type = $run ['type'];

            if ($type == 'd'){

                header("Location: http://www.blubb.php");        }
        else {  //starts html area

?>
```

The code in the beginning for the time check and the `session_destroy` works fine. After the `else {  $check_login = mysql_query` [...] it gets ignored and the page loads even if the account I log in with is `$type == 'd'` .
Can anybody push me in the right direction?

PS: the variables in my mysql table are correct.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The value for `$username` is in my included function.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

function loggedin() {
if(isset($_SESSION['id_user']) && !empty($_SESSION['id_user'])){

    return true;

} else {
    return false;

 }
 }


 if(loggedin()){
 $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT username, user_level FROM users WHERE id='$my_id'");
 $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
 $username = $run_user['username'];
 $user_level = $run_user ['user_level'];
 ?>
```

this is my connect.php for the db connection:

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("host" , "name", "psw");
mysql_select_db("users");

?>
```

Comment: you're missing `exit();` method's after your `header('Location: ...`

Comment: hm, yes, I added it after both `header("Location: http://www.blubb.php"); ` tags, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Either you're missing braces at the end of your code or you didn't show us the rest. Also make sure that the `d` is indeed what the value is and not `D`.

Comment: We also don't know what `$_SESSION['expire']` is and where it's assigned as and its value. Same thing for `$username` and `$password`.

Comment: the `$_SESSION['expire']` doesn't bother me, this is working. I am searching for the username and password values, I guess there is the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with two variables checked up :

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `type` FROM users WHERE id_user = 1 ")) {

        $r = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


        }
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT gruppe FROM users WHERE gruppe = 1 ")) {

        $d = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        }

            $link = 'link.php';     

        if ($_SESSION['type'] == $r['type'] && $_SESSION['gruppe'] == $d['gruppe']) {     
        printf(' <a href="' .$link. '">
                    <button  style="background-image:url(\'ex.jpg\');">                 
                    </button>
                    </a> ');                

                    }
                    else {
                     printf ('
                    <button  style="background-image:url(\'ex.jpg\');">                 
                    </button>
                    ');

      }                             

    $mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in this section make sure that if condition is satisfied.No errors in the code

```
if ($type == 'd'){
           header("Location: http://www.blubb.php");
          }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "satisfied"? The link in the header tag exists, and works for the timecheck tags.

Comment: check whether condition becomes true

Comment: ah okay, do you have any suggestions how I can do that? should I simply add `return true;` after the `if ($type == 'd'){` ? I don't get it atm..

Comment: where is $username and $password values?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you should wrap this whole logic into a class for better practice and maintenance. This allows you to then see exactly what's happening where.

Let's start by creating a router class that lets us specify locations when an action takes place; see [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) if you're confused about object closures.

---

**our_new_router_class.php**

```
class Router {

    const LOGIN = "login.php";
    const HOMEPAGE = "index.php";
    const SITE = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/';

    private $Routes = [];

    public function createRoute($name, $closure) {
        if(is_callable($closure)) {
            $this->Routes[$name] = $closure;
        }
    }

    public function execRoute($name, array $params) {
        return isset($this->Routes[$name]) ? call_user_func_array($this->Routes[$name], $params) : false;
    }

}
```

We can now start adding routes:

```
session_start();
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
require_once("./include/our_new_router_class.php");

$r = new Router();

// Crate a login route
$r->createRoute('Login', function($state) {
    if(!$state) {
        header('Location: http://' . Router::SITE . Router::LOGIN);
        exit();
    }
});

// Execute the login route
$r->execRoute('Login', [$fgmembersite->CheckLogin()]);
```

Since your session expiring is already working, you can try add this yourself. Just to note, they should expire automatically.

---

We can now start the database querying, please note that [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is depreciated in 5.5 and removed in 7.0 so I would recommend using a [new driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) API.

```
$r->createRoute('Type-D', function($state) {
    if($state) {
            header('Location: http://' . Router::SITE . Router::INDEX);
            exit();
        }
});

$sql = "SELECT type FROM users WHERE username='%s'";
// strip any illegal characters out of the name to stop SQL injections
$query = sprintf($sql,mysql_real_escape_string($username));
$results = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // like Manzoor stated in his answer
    $r->execRoute('Type-D', $row['type'] == 'd' ? [true] : [false]);
}
```

---

> **Disclaimer:** This is **not** tested code. Use at your own risk.